# Bought Drupal Organization Membership But Cannot Create Listing

Tags: community-official-site

Recently, I bought DRUPAL ORGANZIATION MEMBERSHIP at $200 but now i am unable add my listing in drupal organzation list. And it also shows "not a confirmed user". Can someone help me with this ??

Comment: Drupal Association Orgranization Membership is not necessarily coupled to Organization listing. You can create an organization here https://www.drupal.org/node/add/organization, but there are some requirements for this and your application needs to be confirmed by the community. And in the first term your user needs to be confirmed (anti-spam policy), read this https://www.drupal.org/node/1887616 (this needs some involvement on the drupal.org pages and/or confirmation from other users).

Comment: Finally if your organization has been approved, you need to link it with your membership, which might need the help of Drupal Association support.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you've already created an organization page for [Elsner Technologies Pvt. Ltd.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313097) on the Drupal marketplace, but that you want the listing to appear as a Drupal services provider.

If this is not yours, you may request its removal, or that ownership of the node is transferred to you so that you can edit it in the [Drupal webmasters issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters).

I've found this [4 year old application](https://www.drupal.org/project/content/issues/2313099) – which was denied.

The [guidelines for being listed in Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/marketplace/services-listing) still apply, and you still do not qualify.  Unfortunately, having a Drupal organization membership does *not* qualify for a listing.  I suggest you re-read the comment given by *lizzjoy* as it contains good advice.

Comment: How can i remove the old listing?? Can please guide me...

Comment: @ElsnerTechnologies Updated answer about removing old listing.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to create an organization is not linked to buying the *Drupal Organization Membership* but to having the *confirmed* role. You need to request the *confirmed* role [in the webmasters' queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters), explaining that you need it to create the organization node. If you don't give that information, the webmasters will postpone the request until you don't post on drupal.org.

As for associating the organization membership with your organization, I cannot reply about that, but it's better to ask for support using the [Drupal Association contact](https://www.drupal.org/association/contact) link. If you choose to contact them online, the *Contact the Drupal Association* green button will redirect you to https://www.drupal.org/contact. Select *Drupal Association membership* as category, enter the subject, the message, and click on *Send message*.

#### Disclaimer

I am one of the Drupal.org webmasters and user administrators.

Comment: Sure..I will submit a request but one more thing is that the organisation member badge doesn't show up. Will it appear once i become confirmed member??

Comment: I guess it will appear when the organization node is created, and you associate the account to that organization.